# Get jQuery Element from currentView

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

In the api docs, the current template instance view can be found using selectors given that the selector's attribute is known ahead of time.

```
template.findAll(selector)
template.$(selector)
```

I also know that it is possible to get the view from Blaze.currentView or template.view, but is it possible to get the jQuery element from Blaze.currentView or template.view? I want to do this because I do not know the template instance's attributes ahead of time.

Comment: I think I'd need more information about what exactly you are trying to do. I'm not sure what you mean by "jQuery element of the view".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the first and last DOM node tied to a template instance or a view using :

- firstNode and lastNode properties on a template instance.
- firstNode() and lastNode() methods on a `Blaze.View` instance.

When you retrieve a DOM element you can build a jQuery object from it using the `$` function as usual.
HTML

```
<template name="test">
  <p>First paragraph</p>
  <p>Last paragraph</p>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.test.rendered=function(){
  var $firstNode=$(this.firstNode);
  $firstNode.css("backgroundColor","red");
  //
  var $lastNode=$(this.view.lastNode());
  $lastNode.css("backgroundColor","green");
};
```

Have a look to `Blaze.View` full documentation over here : http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_view